# Acento agudo e monossílabos

Tags: acordo-ortográfico, acentuação

Vou citar a página da Norma Culta encontrada [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/monossilabos-tonicos-e-atonos/):

> [Monossílabos tônicos] Podem ser ou não acentuados. É apenas
>   obrigatória a acentuação dos monossílabos tônicos terminados em: a,
>   as, e, es, o, os, éu, éus, **éi**, éis, ói, óis.

Depois escrevem

> Exemplos de monossílabos tônicos não acentuados
>
> lei;

A princípio escrevem que se a palavra terminar em "ei" é obrigatória a acentuação, para daí continuar dizendo que "lei" é sem acento. O que é que eu não entendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está mesmo claro na página citada, a palavra chave é *ditongos **abertos***.

A regra é fonológica, baseada na pronúncia: "lei" é fechado ([lêi]), enquanto "réis" é aberto (é o que provavelmente se pretende indicar na listagem citada com o acento em "éu, éus, éi, éis, ói, óis", mas não em "a, as, e, es, o, os").

Em várias outras fontes isso é deixado explícito, por exemplo, no [Mundo Educação](https://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/acentuacao-no-novo-acordo-ortografico.htm) e também no [JurisWay](https://www.jurisway.org.br/v2/pergunta.asp?idmodelo=9746), que escreve:

> Como regra acentuam-se os monossílabos tônicos:
>
> **a)** terminados em **-a**, **-e**, **-o**, seguidos, ou não, de **s**:
>   **Exemplos**: há, pá, pás, má, más, gás, pé, pés, dê, dês, mês, três, crê, só, nó, nós, pôs, etc.
>
> **b)** que encerram os ditongos abertos **-éi**, **-eu**, **-oi**:
>   **Exemplos**: véu, véus, réis, dói, sóis, etc.