# Quando acentuar monossílabas inventadas?

Tags: acentuação

Qual a regra para se acentuar qualquer palavra monossílaba? Algumas palavras acentuadas são acentuadas por convenção ou acentos diferenciais, ou há alguma outra regra que possamos aplicar a qualquer palava?

Vou dar apenas exemplos terminados com "O" e "E" de palavras inventadas:

- *"tô"* (versão encurtada da palavra "estou")
- *"cê"* (versão encurtada da palavra "você")
- *"cé"* (primeira sílaba de nomes como Célia)
- *"Rô"* (primeira sílaba de nomes como Rosangela, Rodrigo, ...)
- *"Rê"* (primeira sílaba de nomes como Renato, Rebeca, ...)
- *"Jô"* (primeira sílaba de nomes como João, Joelma, ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acento agudo e monossílabos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/acento-agudo-e-monoss%c3%adlabos)

Answer (score 4):

Como regra acentuam-se os monossílabos tônicos:

**terminados em -a, -e, -o, seguidos, ou não, de s**:
Exemplos:

há, pá, pás, má, más, gás, pé, pés, dê, dês, mês, três, crê, só, nó, nós, pôs, etc.

**que encerram os ditongos abertos -éi, -eu, -oi:**
Exemplos: véu, véus, réis, dói, sóis, etc.

Não se acentuam os monossílabos tônicos com outras terminações:
Exemplos:

ri, bis, ver, vez, sol, pus, mau, etc..

Comment: Se você fosse escrever "estou" abreviado você escreveria "to" ou "tô"? E como soaria "to"? Como "tó" ou "tô"?

Comment: @Luciano A forma correta de escrita da palavra é estou. Tou e tô são formas abreviadas da palavra estou e devem ser usadas apenas em linguagem falada, em contextos informais.

Comment: Estou ciente da grafia correta. A pergunta é outra.

Answer (score 1):

Eles seguem as regras dos monossílabos tônicos, acentuados com quando terminam em a(s), e(s), o(s) ou ditongos abertos éi(s), éu(s), ói(s).

Não se trata de diferenciar entre tô e tó, a questão é saber: como diferenciar um monossílabo tônico (tem acento) de um átono (não tem acento) se a palavra não tem outras sílabas para compararmos?

Eu diria que todos os exemplos dados na pergunta são tônicos (e levam acento), pois são verbos, pronomes e abreviações de nomes próprios. Palavras átonas geralmente são preposições ou conjunções (ou alguns pronomes também) que são menos enfatizadas dentro de uma frase.

Podemos também comparar o verbo *estar* com o verbo *dar*:

- **tô** se parece com **dou**, mas *to* se pareceria com *do* (preposição + artigo, geralmente pronunciado "du")
- **tá** se parece com **dá**, mas *ta* se pareceria com *da* (preposição + artigo).

Claro que muitas pessoas informalmente não se preocupam em diferenciar *da* de *dá* (o que é uma pena!), mas fazendo um esforço, é possível ver que o jeito de falar essas duas palavras dentro de uma frase é um pouco diferente. Mas bem, já tiraram o diferencial de *para* e *pára*, então sabe-se lá o que o futuro nos reserva.